# Calculating turret angle 2D, C++

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to figure out how I would get the turret on my little space ship to figure out what angle it is at relative to the world and rotate to point to a target

Both the turret and ship have a relative coord and rotation, the ship's coord and rotation are relative to the world and the turret's are relative to its parent(may not be the body of the ship, might be the wing or such)

All parts calculate a local and global 3x3 transformation matrix if that helps

Comment: `atan2` would be the obvious starting point.

Comment: Yeah, figuring out the angle I need to point at the target wouldn't be too hard (touch wood) but it's mostly figuring it the angle of the turret relative to the world, not the parent

Comment: Pretty much, you figure the angle relative to the world, then subtract the angle of the parent.

Comment: I don't know the angle relative to the world, that's the problem

Comment: That's what you compute with `atan2`. Using the x/y location of the turret and the x/y location of the target, it returns their relative angle.

Comment: You know the coordinates of the ship and of the target in the world frame. You know the orientation of the ship in the world frame. From these you get the coordinates of the target in the ship frame. You know the coordinates of the turret in the ship frame, so you can calculate the vector from turret to target in the ship frame. The angle of that vector is the angle the turret must move to. Does that sound right? Which step is giving you trouble?

Comment: This kind of math is well described in books, I like this one: "Essential Mathematics for Games and Interactive Applications, 2nd Edition June 2008" http://www.amazon.ca/dp/0123742978. It's worth buying! You can probably get an electronic copy for cheap.